# Bootstrap3 Replace input-lg with input-sm on small screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I'm using twitter bootstrap's input-lg class on all my inputs. Is there a (maybe javascript) way to replace this with twitter bootstrap's input-sm on smaller screens, so that the  font-size, height, line-height and padding on the input will "shrink" the bootstrap way? Or will it be easier to just do the media-queries myself?

Comment: you would just add the input-sm class together with the input lg that you have

eg: if you have <input class="col-lg-6">

you can make it <input class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">

so that it adjusts itself according to the screen that you are using.
there is already Javascript written in the bootstrap.js file.

hope this helps!

Comment: @PrashanthBenny as far as I know, this only effects the width of the input elements, but neither height, nor line-height nor font-size...

Comment: @PrashanthBenny those are for grids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript (jQuery) way would be (e.g.) something like that (not tested):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $("input").addClass("input-sm");
    }
    else if ($(window).width() >= 768 &&  $(window).width() <= 992) {
        $("input").removeClass("input-sm");
        $("input").removeClass("input-lg");
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 992 &&  $(window).width() <= 1200) {
        $("input").addClass("input-lg");
    }
    else  {
        // do something greater screen sizes if you want
    }
});
```

I think that would be a better solution, because with writing your own media queries, you just copy bootstraps CSS for these existing classes... But if you prefer that, [this post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries) will be a good start.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot. thanks  also for the bonus screen sizes, though I needed for just 768. see my edit.

Comment: Yes, use it as you like. Your edit can be posted as an editional answer, as it removes some screen sizes - this solution is a bit more general.